# Entity Translation: Translate breadcrumb

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, i18n-l10n

I'm having issues translating breadcrumb.
Everything works, menu items, strings etc... a part from breadcrumb.

I've tried [hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7) to reset the title with no success.

How can I translate breadcrumb?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that string(those are not getting translated) into backend, using translate interface- http://example.com/admin/config/regional/translate/translate

Comment: This method does not work for me. Where is the breadcrumb get generated?